# Как запустить сервер Django 2.0.3 из Terminal в PyCharm 2017.3.3?

Tags: django

Пробую так: E:\OK\0-Проекты\ЗАПЧАТИ\Python\User_Project\dj_1>manage.py runserver
Ошибок не показывает, но в браузере  ничего из этого не срабатывает:
http://127.0.0.1:8000 
localhost:8080

Может команда в Django 2 изменилась? Они там это любят...

Answer (score 1):

manage.py runserver - сработает если только у вас правильно настроено окружение.
Т.к. Django 2.0 поддерживает только Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. То старый код в котором прописан второй питон не будет работать правильно.

Запуск лучше делать с явным указанием программы

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

Проверка на ошибки

```
python3 manage.py check
```

Comment: И, желательно, чтобы в пути не содержались папки или файлы с названиями на кириллице ;-)